# How do I set up php 7 to use a different php.ini for cli and apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php7

When I installed php5 using `apt-get`, it seemed to be configured to use:

- `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` for the cli binary
- `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` when running through apache

I cannot find anything in any configuration files that seems to set up this behaviour.

I want to do the same thing with php7. I've compiled it with:

```
--with-config-file-path=/etc/php7/apache2/
--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php7/apache2/conf.d/
```

But that seems to make it use that directory for *both* the cli and apache (when I do `php -i` I see it loaded the `php.ini` in `/etc/php7/apache2`).

How do I make it use a different file for the cli?

Answer (score 1):

I simply ended up compiling the apache module and cli separately.

Answer (score -1):

With the native install of php7.0, no compilation is needed.
The directory to the config for php7 is 
/etc/php/7.0/cli 
i search the same file for apache2 and not find (again)
See you later :-)